# MySQL: Using a reference id, see if data matches across that id

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
id   |    data     |     reference_id
1         Jacob          3
2         Apples         3
3         Henry          4
4         Pie            4
5         Jacob          5
6         Pears          5
```

What I'm trying to do is build a query that checks if data exists in the same reference_id given the data.

So basically:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE data='Jacob' AND data='Apples' AND 
...(reference_id's are the same)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) WHERE data='Jacob' AND data='Apples' GROUP BY reference_id;
```